# Is it acceptable to promote related nascent Area 51 sites

Tags: discussion

I have set up a proposal for a new Stack Exchange site on Area 51 - "[Transportation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3620)". There is probably a good deal of cross-interest between people that post in GIS and people that might potentially post in Transportation, and one of the followers has suggested promoting it here. Is it acceptable to promote the site on GIS (meta I presume), or would that be considered undermining this site?

Comment: +1 yeah especially overlap with [ITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_transportation).

Comment: Also, maybe SE would be willing to sponsor someone to attend [GIS-T Symposium](http://www.gis-t.org/).

Comment: That looks like a good conference - wish we had something like that in the UK!

Comment: Too bad I missed it.

Answer (score 7):

[Other sites](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/961/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) have tolerated meta threads for Area 51 promotion.  I don't think promotion here would undermine this site.  In general I do think promotion of other sites, whether nascent or mature, should have a clear relationship to our GIS focus.